# What does "$\sim$" mean here? $F(w_i-w_j,\tilde w_k)=\frac{P_{ik}}{P_{jk}}$

Tags: notation

What does this "$\sim$" symbol mean? For example,
$$F(w_i-w_j,\tilde w_k)=\frac{P_{ik}}{P_{jk}}$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: We need more context

Comment: Where did you come across this expression? It really should be mentioned there what it means.

Comment: Guys, generally I need to know what is ~ in mathematics?

Comment: from notation tag info : "Please remember to mention where (book, paper, webpage, etc.) you encountered any mathematical notation you are asking about." notation is context dependent.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: I suspect they are indicating that $\tilde w_k$ belongs to a distinct set: $\tilde w_k\neq w_k$. But yes you have to give more context.

Answer (score 2):

It varies according to context.

Sometimes it's used to denote another, related concept, variable, etc., to the one without the tilde; for instance, it might help readers to note that $w$ and $x$ are similar in structure, so $x$ would be written as $\tilde w$.

Sometimes it is used as a binary operation; for example, $a\sim b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are in the same coset of a quotient group of a group.

Sometimes it's used above equality signs to denote some weaker sense of equality, like an isomorphism; for example, $A\cong B$ for groups $A, B$ means "$A$ is isomorphic to $B$ as a group."

Doubtless, there are countless many other uses too.

Comment: (+1) I've also seen it as a symbol for the transpose.

Comment: or a column vector in PARI/GP